# obtener la última id insertada

Tags: angular

Estoy insertando unos datos en mi base de datos, pero necesito obtener la id que acabo de insertar, yo el campo id se lo mando nulo, por lo que a la hora de insertarlo en la base de datos se lo manda nulo pero al ser autoincrementable le da un valor, necesito obtener ese valor de ese campo específico cómo podría obtenerlo?

Comment: Sería de ayuda que indicaras que base de datos usas, ya que algunas tienen funcionalidades especiales que te te pueden ayudar. Además la etiqueta "angular" no tiene mucho sentido en tu pregunta en este caso.

Comment: Que has intentado?... muéstranos algo de código para tener un panorama mas detallado de tu problema.

Comment: si es sql busca el id mas alto, si el id es autoincremental es que cada vez es +1 del anterior Select MAX (CODIGO) from DB